# Append data to beginning of CSV file

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm working on an Access application and I've run into the following snag. Currently I'm writing an output file by exporting a query as a CSV file, however this file needs to be read by an older database system and will need a header row containing some identifying data.

I can construct the string for this header row in VBA without any trouble, but I'm not quite sure how to insert it in the first line of the CSV file, rather than it being appended at the end. How can I do this/achieve the desired result?

Comment: Can you post the code your using to generate your CSV file. The built in export functions include an option to include the header.

Comment: @andshrew I'm not looking to include field headers, to clear that up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the file, read it, write the header, write back the data:

```
Dim data As String
Dim hF As Integer: hF = FreeFile()

Open "c:\path\foo.csv" For Input As #hF
   data = Input$(LOF(hF), #hF)
Close #hF

Open "c:\path\foo.csv" For Output As #hF
   Print #hF, "Header data here" & vbCrLf & data
Close #hF
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider explicitly labeling your query columns with the corresponding header column as aliases. Then, export to csv with these headers using the VBA method, [TransferText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx):

**SQL**

```
SELECT Col1 As Header1,
       Col2 As Header2,
       Col3 As Header3,
       Col4 As Header4
       ...
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.PKID = Table2.FKID
```

**VBA**

```
Dim csvpath As String

csvpath = "C:\Path\To\CSVFile.csv"
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "QueryName", csvpath, True
```